# Parsing special markup with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text containing some special markup. A colon is separating two integers to indicate that this will be a link to a special page/file/document.

Its syntax is `DOC_ID:SECTION_ID` with `@` sign *optional* in-front.

How can I replace this special markup with a regular HTML link, removing the `@` sign if there are any?

**Original text:**

`Lorem ipsum @2:6 dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 5:22 fermentum ex. @99:12 Mauris euismod lacus ut lacus maximus laoreet 44:9.`

**Output:**

`Lorem ipsum <a href="/document/2/section/6">2:6</a> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing <a href="/document/5/section/22">5:22</a> fermentum ex. <a href="/document/99/section/12">99:12</a> Mauris euismod lacus ut lacus maximus laoreet <a href="/document/44/section/9">44:9</a>.`

Comment: Did you try to write some code yourself?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the regex you're looking for is

```
@?(\d+):(\d+)
```

You would use it this way:

```
var newStr = str.replace(/@?(\d+):(\d+)/g, '<a href="/document/$1/section/$2">$1:$2</a>');
```

Would highly recommend you get acquainted with [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) and the [replace function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for further reference.